# Adding a button type to joomla plugin xml config

Tags: php, xml, joomla, content-management-system, config

I have created a joomla plugin and added 2 fields in xml file with the below code. I want to add a button type. As I don't find the button type in joomla, how to achieve this? I am using Joomla v4.

```
             <fieldset name="basic">
                 <field
                        name="email"
                        type="text"
                        filter="raw"
                        default=""
                        label="PLG_EDITORS-XTD_XXX_FIELD_EMAIL"
                        description="Enter your XXX Email"
                        size="50"/>
                <field
                        name="password"
                        type="password"
                        label="PLG_EDITORS-XTD_XXX_FIELD_PASSWORD"
                        description="Enter the password"
                        maxlength="25"
                        size="30"/>
            </fieldset>
```

Please refer the screenshot for better clarity on what I was looking for.
[image: Joomla config screen]

Answer (score 1):

You need to build a custom field type, store it in your plugin and load it in your plugin's XML file.

Take a look at `plugins/system/stats` plugin. It defines the custom field type `data` like this:

```
            <fieldset name="basic" addfieldprefix="Joomla\Plugin\System\Stats\Field">
                <field
                    name="data"
                    type="data"
                    label=""
                />
            </fieldset>
```

The `data` field is stored in `plugins/system/stats/src/Field/DataField.php`, the final HTML is rendered from the layout `plugins/system/stats/layouts/field/data.php`. In your case, your custom field type's layout is the one rendering the login button.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a field for the Login button, the field will be custom type, lets name it loginbtn:

   ```
         <fieldset name="basic" addfieldprefix="Joomla\Plugin\<Your plugin group>\<Your plugin name>\Field">
             <field
                    name="email"
                    type="text"
                    filter="raw"
                    default=""
                    label="PLG_EDITORS-XTD_XXX_FIELD_EMAIL"
                    description="Enter your XXX Email"
                    size="50"/>
            <field
                    name="password"
                    type="password"
                    label="PLG_EDITORS-XTD_XXX_FIELD_LOGINBTN"
                    description="Login"/>
        </fieldset>
   ```
2. Create a file, Loginbtn.php in plugins/< Your plugin group >/< Your plugin name >/src/Field

Loginbtn.php code:

```
<?php
defined('JPATH_PLATFORM') or die;

use Joomla\CMS\Factory;
use Joomla\CMS\Form\FormField;

class JFormFieldLoginbtn extends FormField
{
    protected $type = 'loginbtn';

    protected function getInput()
    {
        $html = '<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="your btn class" />';

        return $html;
    }

    public function getLabel() {
        return '<span style="text-decoration: underline;">' . parent::getLabel() . '</span>';
    }
}
```

4. Add a folder for Field in plugin's xml 
   < folder >field< /folder >